# How do I overwrite an existing file on an ftp server in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I can't upload the same file twice in a row (second time, the content is updated), I get the following, how do i fix it??

```
Connected successfully uploading file: /tmp/Mall_bill_extract_20120213_170429_2.csv
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/operations/upload.rb:313:in `on_open'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `to_proc'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/request.rb:87:in `call'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/request.rb:87:in `respond_to'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:948:in `dispatch_request'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:911:in `when_channel_polled'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `to_proc'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `call'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `process'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:214:in `preprocess'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:214:in `each'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:214:in `preprocess'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:197:in `process'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop_forever'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:802:in `loop'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@vitality_mall/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp.rb:35:in `start'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/app/controllers/report_purchases_employer_controller.rb:139:in `export_to_bill_csv'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1253:in `send'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1253:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:136:in `perform_action_without_caching'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:13:in `perform_action'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in `perform_action'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `send'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `process_without_filters'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in `process'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in `process'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in `handle_request'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:103:in `handle_dispatch'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:74:in `service'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:60:in `dispatch'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:49
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/kamilski81/Sites/pe/rails-apps/vitality_mall/script/server:3
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta5/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_load'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta5/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_program'
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta5/bin/rdebug-ide:87
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1
```

here is the code:

```
begin
  Net::SFTP.start('localhost', 'user', :password=>'pass') do |sftp|
    sftp.upload file_location, "/test/outbound_transactions/#{file_name}"
  end
rescue => ex
  puts ex.backtrace
end
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is failing rather than the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data safety, you should:

1. Upload the new file to a temporary filename.
2. Rename the original to a `.bak` version.
3. Rename the newly uploaded version to the original name.
4. Delete the original.

The reason for this is, you want to have one of the versions available if the code or connection fails for some reason.

That could also step around the problem you're seeing.

I have seen FTP hosts lock the file immediately after it's been uploaded. I don't know why, because, when their server screwed up it made it impossible for me to delete the file. So, they could be locking/changing permissions or changing ownership of the file immediately after upload.

The backtrace doesn't help a whole lot because we don't get the message contained in `ex`. You should do:

```
puts ex.message
```

or:

```
puts ex.to_s
```

before the `puts ex.backtrace` to get the actual message.

The code that raised the exception doesn't tell us much either:

```
# Called when an +open+ request finishes. Raises StatusException if the
# open failed, otherwise it calls #write_next_chunk to begin sending
# data to the remote server.
def on_open(response)
  @active -= 1
  file = response.request[:file]
  raise StatusException.new(response, "open #{file.remote}") unless response.ok?
  [...]
```

so the `puts ex.message` would help you out.

Also, `upload` is asynchronous, so you might want to add a `wait`. This is from [the docs](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/classes/Net/SFTP/Session.html#M000115):

> Initiates an upload from local to remote, asynchronously. This method will return a new Net::SFTP::Operations::Upload instance, and requires the event loop to be run in order for the upload to progress. See Net::SFTP::Operations::Upload for a full discussion of how this method can be used.

```
  uploader = sftp.upload("/local/path", "/remote/path")
  uploader.wait
```